# XULRunner is not available in Ubuntu, how do I run XUL apps?

Tags: firefox, xulrunner

XULRunner is not available as a package any more on Ubuntu, so what is the easiest way run XUL applications in that situation?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I have found for doing this is to use firefox's built-in XULRunner - of course this entails installing firefox (which is quite large) instead of just XULRunner (which is smaller), but I prefer doing that because I want the distribution to manage all package updates.

Simply start your application with:

```
firefox -app /path/to/application.ini
```